# c++ is it possible to gain access to an alias (using) from an instance

Tags: c++, using

I have Buffer with type and size set by template.

I store the type with a `using`, and allow access to the size with a method.

Everything's fine with the size. Now, can I gain access to the type (like in line
`Buffer<char,6>::value_type  val = 'z';` ) but from an instance of Buffer?

I tried the commented syntax, but failed:

```
//g++  5.4.0
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, int N>
struct Buffer {
    using value_type = T;
    constexpr int size() { return N; }
    T tab [N];
    Buffer(T val) { for(int _i; _i<N ; _i++){ tab[_i]=val; } }
    void p(){ for(int _i; _i<N ; _i++){ cout << tab[_i] << " "; } }
};

int main()
{
    Buffer<char,6> b( 'x' );
    cout << "there will be " << b.size() << " values : ";
    b.p();
    cout << endl;
    Buffer<char,6>::value_type  val = 'z';
    // b.value_type val = 'z'; // error: invalid use of ‘using value_type = char’
    // b::value_type val = 'z'; // error: ‘b_c’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you try a `typedef` instead of `using`?

Comment: ok, and then which syntax from instance b. because I changed to "typedef T value_type;" but none of the commented syntax work (error messages remain unchanged)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That won't make a difference.  A `typedef` and `using` alias have the same mechanics.

Comment: Are you looking for [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike static class members, type names need to be accessed from the class name, not the instance name.  All is not lost though, you can use `decltype` to get the class name from an instance and then you can access the type name like

```
decltype(b)::value_type foo = 'a';
```

Comment: @chetzacoalt In `decltype(b.tab[0])`, `tab[0]` returns a `char&` so that becomes the type of `foo`.  You can't initialize a `char&` with an prvalue (what `'f'` is).